# Diagnosing slow views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

My view in Rails sometimes render so slow that it's become unbearable

```
Completed 200 OK in 88765.5ms (Views: 88132.3ms | ActiveRecord: 13.0ms)
```

I am using a Rails 3.2.15 app. The view seems to be slow when recompiling CSS (changes have been made), simple view reloading is fine. However, I can't find anything that would be unreasonable in there.

What tool or technique can I use to locate the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck with the rack-mini-profiler gem.

More info can be found here:

https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler

and here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't seem effective in my case, it just shows layouts/application taking up 99.9% but what...